# Is there a way to specify -feature to the fsc Ant task?

Tags: scala, fsc

I've been compiling my scala code through the fsc Ant task and keep getting the following warning:

```
warning: there were 3 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
two warnings found
```

I understand that passing `-feature` to scalac will print a detailed report about the warnings I'm getting and, more often than not, good suggestions as to how they should be fixed.

I can't however for the life of me work out how to pass this argument to the `fsc` task. Is it not supported (yet)? Am I missing something obvious that will make me regret asking this question later?

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell, the only option is to use `sbt` instead...

Answer (score 0):

Please try below, according to scala doc, fsc ant task should share same attributes with scalac

```
<scalac srcdir="${scala.src.dir}"
    destdir="${build.dir}"
    classpathref="build.classpath"
    addparams="-feature">
    <include name="**/*.scala"   />
</scalac>
```